# Popup show when exit and return to view

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog

In my application I have a delete popup. The problem is when I click on delete the popup show and I click cancel after that when I exit the page and return to it again, the popup shows again! I don't have any idea why.

Here's my controller,

```
public function deletePopup()
{
    $questionId = (Input::get('question_id'));
        Session::flash('popup', $questionId); 
        return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

And my view,

```
 <form action={{ url("popupQuestion") }} method="post">


    <input type="text" class="Question_id hiden" name="question_id" value="<?php echo $question->question_id ?>" />

    <input style="margin-bottom: -8px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger boutton-delete" value="Supprimer">


</form>
  @if(Session::has('popup'))
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal();
        });
    </script>
   <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content center">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Suppression</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
           <h5> Attention, vous allez supprimer une question. cette action est irréversible</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer ">

          <form action={{ url("deleteQuestion") }} method="post">

            <input type="text" class="hiden " name="question_id" value={{ Session::get('popup') }} />
             <input type="text" class="hiden " name="pop" value="1" }} />

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" type="submit" value="OK" />
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-info close-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Annuller</button>
          </form>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>   
    @endif
```

Comment: When the page reloads it checks for `@if(Session::has('popup'))` and runs the script below it. For each delete or page refresh, unset the popup session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Place this at the bottom of your `@if(Session::has)` before its closing `@endif`:

```
Session::forget('popup');
```

Additionally, Laravel has a handy package for notifications that can give you more flexibility:
https://github.com/edvinaskrucas/notification

Answer (score 0):

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    $response->headers->set('Pragma','no-cache');
    $response->headers->set('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
})
```

try to place this code inside routes.php file in app folder. It will clear the cache. Cache may be the problem.